# How to find out what is causing a script to run on boot?

Tags: startup, debian

I have a script running on boot which should not run until networking has setup. I am trying to find the source but reaching dead end. Is it possible to trace how a script has started in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is not easy. Admin hack is to install some audit system to collect such things (e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux) or see package `acct` but then how do you determine if such and such line is the script you are seeking for. BTW why do you think it has run, was there some output?